# Overriding parameters.yml values dynamically after running composer install in symfony

Tags: symfony

This:

```
parameters_dev.yml.dist
   my_key: todays_timestamp_{$timestamp}
```

would generate:

```
parameters.yml
   my_key: todays_timestamp_9845712365
```

after running `composer install`

Is this possible yet or any workaround? What I'm trying to achieve is, everytime when I run `composer install`, `my_key` will have a unique value.

---

**UPDATE**

config.yml

```
doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        my_memcached_cache:
            namespace: %cache_namespace%
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    cache_namespace: todays_timestamp_
```

Memcache stats will always be like this:

```
Server 127.0.0.1:11211
stats cachedump 12 100

Server 127.0.0.1:11211
ITEM todays_timestamp_[My\Bundle\Acc][1] [1807 b; 1438597305 s]
ITEM todays_timestamp_[My\Bundle\Mer][1] [1707 b; 1438597305 s]
.....
.....
END
```

but I want `todays_timestamp_` to be changed all the time with attaching a unique suffix to it.

Comment: On prod your parameters and container would only be built once so you could create the parameter in your extension and it would only happen the one time per deploy/cache warmup.

Comment: Hence reason I needed such thing. Everytime the app is deployed to prod, stag etc. with capifony or whatever, this value in parameters.yml must change.

Comment: But with `capifony` your parameters should be in a shared file so you would be editing your only parameters file each time. What is is that you are actually wanting to do with this.. beyond have a unique key. What is the purpose of the key?

Comment: My memcached must use different namespaces for each apps which are hosted in same server and use same memcached instance. I cannot really `flush_all` memcached cos other apps would crash. The whole idea is to set a unique namespace for memcached, that's all. I updated the question.

Comment: I hope my answer makes a little more sense.... and actually works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your container parameters are only generally created on cache warmup you can create the parameter in your `XxxExtension` on each deploy. From here you can use then `prepend` your configuration for `doctrine_cache` rather than needing to do it the other way around.

In your extension you can do the following...

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

// implement the PrependExtensionInterface so it gets picked up by the DI
class AcmeHelloExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    // Add your usual extension stuff

    // add the prepend method to prepend your config onto the doctrine_cache config
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // check for the presence of the doctrine_cache bundle and throw an exception
        if (!$container->hasExtension('doctrine_cache')) {
            throw new \Exception('DoctrineCacheBundle must be registered in kernel');
        }

        // add your config with your timestamp to the doctrine_cache config
        $container->prependExtensionConfig(
            'doctrine_cache',
            array(
                'providers' => array(
                    'my_memcached_cache' => array(
                        'namespace' => sprintf(
                            // your cache key with timestamp
                            'memcache_timestamp_%s',
                            \DateTime::getTimestamp()
                        ),
                     ),
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This way each time the container is compiled it should rebuild the config for `doctrine_cache` with your timestamped cache key updated to "now" stopping you needing to hook into composer updates or anything like that.

For more info on the [`PrependExtension` stuff check out the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it tomorrow and update you. Also was that `if()` statement necessary? Why are we checking mongo?

Comment: Sorry, I copied it from some of my own code. The `if()` isn't entirely necessary but could be handy in the future. Without that check your config would just have the `doctrine_cache` key added meaning that, if for some reason you removed the DoctrineCacheBundle, you would just get errors saying something like `There is no extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine_cache"` rather than being able to specify where the config is being added.

Comment: I'll be using this cos it worked as wanted so plus 1 and thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I do a similar think for the asset version management. Practically, I suggest you the following approach:

```
<?php
// app/config/cache_namespace_version.php
        $container->loadFromExtension('doctrine_cache', array(
                'providers' => array(
                    'my_memcached_cache' => array(
                        'namespace' => exec('git rev-parse --short HEAD'),  // Or the current timestamp
                    ),
                )));
```

And import in the config_prod.ml

```
# app/config/config.yml

imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: cache_namespace_version.php }
```

You can use the current timestamp instead of the git hash commit, depends if you want to change the key every cache clear or only if the code change.

Check that I have injected the correct doctrine_cache key into the container. Inspired by [this article](http://blog.lavoie.sl/2012/10/automatic-cache-busting-using-git-in-symfony2.html)

Hope this help

Comment: I'll remember and note this option somewhere cos it is interesting. Plus 1.